# IIS on Windows 8.1 makes system hang on preload

Tags: windows-8.1

After installing Windows 8.1 I started getting random hangs. Running apps would become unresponsive, and may even trigger Windows to want to close them out.  I have narrowed it down to then I make a change to a website for development.

The only thing I can guess is that IIS is doing something that is overwhelming my system.

I have Googled this problem extensively, and yet haven't found a solution.

Has any of you had this problem and fixed it.

**UPDATE

The eventlog shows the following error, over and over, like 7 times a second.

```
The machine-default permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{C2F03A33-21F5-47FA-B4BB-156362A2F239}
 and APPID 
{316CDED5-E4AE-4B15-9113-7055D84DCC97}
 to the user NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE SID (S-1-5-19) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.
```

I am now heading to Google to see if I can solve this myself, but if any of you have seen it before and can help, I do appreciate it.

Extra information:

- This doesn't happen on Windows 7.
- It only happens after compiling an ASP.Net app and then loading it in a web browser
- I am not 100% sure, but I think it may only be MVC apps

System Properties:

Intel Core i7-2600 3.4GHz

16 Gigs of ram

Comment: Check the Event Logs in the System folder and see if the OS is screaming about memory stuff like page file or pool, and see if there are any other errors around the time of crashes. If you haven't already, you should check the Application's section too.

Comment: I have no idea why I never bothered to check the event logs.  I am smarter than that.  I have updated the question.  The error is in the System event log